# Set Query Value To NULL in store procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to set a query value to NULL in a stored procedure:

The query should be:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[tablesym] SET PAYMSTTS=0,SWP=0,IDRM=NULL
```

so, in the stored procedure, I have:

```
SELECT @query21= 'UPDATE [dbo].[tablesym] SET PAYMSTTS=0,SWP=0,IDRM='+NULL
```

However, the column does not update. Neither any error is thrown, nor any update has been made in tablesym.

Comment: You might wanna add a `WHERE` clause?

Comment: No issue with your Query, you might doing some other mistake which is not showing here..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT @query21= 'UPDATE [dbo].[tablesym] SET PAYMSTTS=0,SWP=0,IDRM='+NULL

select @query21 -- will result in NULL
```

As simple as that you add anything to infinity result will always be infinity.

This is what you need

```
SELECT @query21= 'UPDATE [dbo].[tablesym] SET PAYMSTTS=0,SWP=0,IDRM= NULL'
```

If you are working with some variables, you may have to use

```
SELECT @query21= 'UPDATE [dbo].[tablesym] SET PAYMSTTS=0,SWP=0,IDRM= ' 
 + ISNULL(@IDRM, 'NULL')
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the line in your stored proc to this:

```
SELECT @query21= 'UPDATE [dbo].[tablesym] SET PAYMSTTS=0,SWP=0,IDRM=NULL'
```

Answer (score 0):

Concatenating string with null will return null always.write null inside the quotes.

Comment: At *present*, your "always" statement is incorrect. See [`SET CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176056.aspx). At some point in the future, you will be able to say this (see same page) but only for some future version of SQL Server.